# Adding Specific columns values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add two specific values in R. I am new to R and so far I have used colSums and it does give me the right values. However, I was wondering if there was a way to add specific cells and then add as them as row to the dataframe. In this case, I would like to add the last two columns.

Here's sample data:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | a |
| 2 | 4 | b |
| 1 | 5 | c |

Desired output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | a |
| 3 | 9 | b&c |

Answer (score 1):

Admittingly, this is not pretty as it mixes `tidyverse` and base R. But, we can use a custom function, since we are dealing with columns of different classes, i.e `colSums` will not work because `"a" + "b"` is not `"ab"`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <-
  tribble(
    ~col1, ~col2, ~col3,
    3, 7, "a",
    2, 4, "b",
    1, 5, "c"
  )

f <- function(df) {
  replace <- df %>%
    tail(2) %>%
    summarise(
      col1 = sum(col1),
      col2 = sum(col2),
      col3 = paste0(col3, collapse = "&")
    )
  bind_rows(
    df %>% head(-2),
    replace
  )
}

df %>%
  f()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>    col1  col2 col3 
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     3     7 a    
#> 2     3     9 b&c
```

Comment: Glad it worked. For future reference - consider accepting an answer that satisfies your needs best, it is generally the best way to express gratitude. 


  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment